# DevExpress DateEdit using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have just started using the 
<% Html.DevExpress().DateEdit() 
control and i got it to work fine in my ASP.Net MVC application. The code is as shown below:

aspx page:

`<% Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "EndDate";
        settings.Properties.NullText = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        settings.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
        settings.Properties.EditFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        settings.Date = Model.EndDate;
        settings.Width = 100;

     }
).Render();
%>`

Above this code i have a reference to my javascript file (DateChanges.js) in this file i want to be able to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#EndDate").change(function(){
        //do whatever i want
    });

})
```

I cant do this now cause using firefox i can see that the actual textbox that this datepicker assigns a value to has be named "EndDate_I". So my question is how can i easily do this since i want to be able to catch the change event of this control and play around with it in jQuery??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DevExpress MVC Extensions offer their own infrastructure for the client-side processing needs (see the http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument6908 help topic to getting started).

It is necessary to handle the client-side ASPxClientDateEdit.DateChanged event, and retrieve the newly selected Date via the client-side ASPxClientDateEdit.GetDate() method. Use the retrieved js Date object for your additional needs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnDateChanged(s, e) {
        var newDate = s.GetDate();
        alert(newDate);
    }
</script>

settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.DateChanged = "OnDateChanged";
```

Comment: thanks, the above works but just partly solves my problem.  I still want to be able to access this control using some sort of id or identifier in javascript.  I have two DateEdit controls on my page and a label to display the difference in days when either of this date edits values are changed.  So from my referenced javascript file i want to be able to do something like this: ------------------function OnDateChanged(s, e){  var startdate= s.GetDate(); 
var enddate = //get the enddate from the second DateEdit control --CalculateDayDifference(startdate, enddate);  }

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather long Blog post at http://kennytordeur.blogspot.com/2011/05/aspnet-mvc-where-is-clientid_10.html discussing your problem

( I think it is to long to have it pasted here, and the author deserves the credits )

Answer (score 0):

following on from your comment on Mikhails's answer, there will be a property in the global namespace with the name of your control, so it's just like this:

```
CalculateDayDifference(s.GetDate(), EndDate.GetDate());
```

All the mvc controls do this, for some you might have to set the EnableClientSideApi property to start using them.